# Keycloak jwt expired

Tags: jwt, jhipster, keycloak

I am creating an application with Jhipster. To do this, I want to use the Keycloak authentication server. But as soon as I log in I get the following message :
Statut : Internal Server Error (Internal Server Error)
Message : An error occurred while attempting to decode the Jwt: Jwt expired at 2019-06-04T00:20:05Z

My .yo-rc.json :

```
{
"generator-jhipster": {
"promptValues": {
  "packageName": "com.mycompany.front.project",
  "nativeLanguage": "fr"
},
"jhipsterVersion": "6.0.1",
"applicationType": "gateway",
"baseName": "frontProduit",
"packageName": "com.mycompany.front.project",
"packageFolder": "com/mycompany/front/project",
"serverPort": "8080",
"authenticationType": "oauth2",
"cacheProvider": "ehcache",
"enableHibernateCache": true,
"websocket": false,
"databaseType": "sql",
"devDatabaseType": "postgresql",
"prodDatabaseType": "postgresql",
"searchEngine": false,
"messageBroker": false,
"serviceDiscoveryType": "consul",
"buildTool": "maven",
"enableSwaggerCodegen": false,
"clientFramework": "angularX",
"clientTheme": "none",
"clientThemeVariant": "",
"useSass": true,
"clientPackageManager": "npm",
"testFrameworks": [],
"jhiPrefix": "jhi",
"entitySuffix": "",
"dtoSuffix": "DTO",
"otherModules": [],
"enableTranslation": true,
"nativeLanguage": "fr",
"languages": [
  "fr",
  "en"
]
}
}
```

Comment: Can you please include the `.yo-rc.json` for your app so we can try and reproduce the problem?

Comment: I modify my answer

Comment: Help me please !

Comment: Can you confirm that the clock on your computer matches an internet clock like https://www.time.gov/?

Comment: Yes my clock matches a world clock

Comment: I had someone report a similar issue recently. Strangely, regenerating their project solved the problem. I'm not sure why.

Comment: I have already run the mv command several times to regenerate

Comment: Help me it's very urgent

Answer (score 7):

This problem haunted me for 3 days but I finally figured it out. It has to do with the local Docker client time getting out of sync with your OS. This happens particularly when you put the computer to sleep. That is when Docker experiences "time drift". The solution is to restart the Docker client before you run your Keycloak image.

If you are running Keycloak on a different machine, then it would have to have the same date time set to the machine that runs the java server.